# İn Unity Photon Network , Learn who did the bullet come from?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon, photon-pun

I make a game using photon network . 2 actors are shooting at each other and when the bullet is formed on the stage I want to know who the bullet came from. I can send player id in bullet Instantiate and I can find player in for loop but i don't think it's true.

Is there better than this method?

Code

```
    void Shoot()
    {
        var part = GetComponentInChildren<ParticleSystem>();
        part.Play();
        float angle = cc.isFacingRight ? 0f : 180f;

        GameObject gameob = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Bullet", firingPoint.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, angle)),0, null);
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `photonView.Owner`, since the bullet is a networked object. Alternatively, you can use `photonView.IsMine` to check if the client running the check owns the bullet, instead of comparing owners.

(The `photonView` instance comes from assuming your bullet script extends `MonoBehaviourPun` instead of `MonoBehaviour`)